# Coloring scatter chart markers

Tags: excel, vba, charts, scatter

I have a scatter chart where series are configured using VBA in the chart from a table.
I am required to provide specific marker colors for each series different for each series point.

I tried to set up the code but whenever MACRO button clicked every time the color is changed on its own and the required color configuration is lost. I am not able get how to stop and fix the required color for each series.

Kind help is needed.  I tried to record MACRO too, but the same problem happens. Code from the file as below. Where am I making mistakes?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    Selection.MarkerStyle = 1
    Selection.MarkerSize = 10
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(252, 213, 181)
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    Selection.MarkerStyle = 2
    Selection.MarkerSize = 10
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground2
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
    Selection.MarkerStyle = 3
    Selection.MarkerSize = 10
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
'fourth series
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
    With Selection
        .MarkerStyle = 8
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Format.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Format.Fill.Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
    With Selection
        .MarkerStyle = 8
        .MarkerSize = 10
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Select
    Selection.MarkerStyle = 9
    Selection.MarkerSize = 10
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the chart formatting object model in VBA is out of synch with the user interface in numerous ways. You should use something like this (which also cleans up your original code somewhat):

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
  With .FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .MarkerStyle = 1
    .MarkerSize = 10
    .MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(252, 213, 181)
    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(252, 213, 181)
  End With
End With
```

`MarkerForegroundColor` represents the line part of the marker and `MarkerBackgroundColor` the fill part.